# MERN stack - Cannot find module - module.exports = mongoose.model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm following this MERN stack tutorial and stuck on this video about models and schemas, starting around minute 7: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8IipcpTmYU&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iJ_KkrkBZWZRHVwnzLIoUE&index=5

I created a schema with mongoose, exported, and when requiring it in my routes file it can't be found.

**File structure:**

```
MERN
| client/
| models/
|  - workoutModel.js
| server/
|  - node_modules/
|  - routes/
|  -- workouts.js
|  - .env
|  - package-lock.json
|  - package.json
|  - server.js
```

**workouts.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Workout = require('../models/workoutModel.js');

// /api/workouts/
// GET all workouts
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'GET all workouts'})
})

// GET single workout
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'GET single workout'})
})

// POST new workout
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
     
})

// DELETE a workout
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'DELETE a workout'})
})

// UPDATE a workout
router.patch('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'UPDATE a workout'})
})

module.exports = router;
```

**workoutModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const workoutSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    reps: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    load: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Workout', workoutSchema);
```

Here is my error:

```
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../models/workoutModel.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\USER\Documents\MERN\server\routes\workouts.js
- C:\Users\USER\Documents\MERN\server\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\MERN\server\routes\workouts.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\MERN\server\server.js:11:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\MERN\\server\\routes\\workouts.js',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\MERN\\server\\server.js'
  ]
}
```

I've followed the tutorial word for word, and I have no idea what is wrong! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ps - the contents of the 'post' method are blank because I had made a change (different from the other methods) and was trying to make sure that wasn't the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this code would be like this

```
const Workout = require('../../models/workoutModel.js');
```

You should check the file path again

Comment: I thought I tried that before but I guess this was the problem! I also recently heard ../ indicates up 2 levels, must be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once with this line?

```
const Workout = require('../models/workoutModel');
```